# Implementing Spring Transaction Handling in an already existing class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, transactions

I've ran into some errors with my local HSQLDB and think that I am in need of a transaction handling system.

The Spring Framework seems to be the most common choice for that, but all tutorials I read online implemented DAOPatterns, DAOs, etc.

Is there a possibility to just set the transaction handling component on top of my already implemented class?

I can't rewrite my whole application and basically got everything working already...

best regards
daZza

Comment: you can build a middle layer on top of your existing components, which works with spring transaction handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You "can" handle transaction at every level, but it's just not recommended.

Daos are usually meant to handle operations with the database, but usually not transactions which are supposed to be on the service level.

Why? Well Dao methods should do something simple, like updating an entry or finding one.

The important thing to remember about transactions is that they should be [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

And handling transactions you should then make sure that your database will be in a correct state should a rollback occcur.
Imagine you are doing the following operations (textbook): taking money from one account and putting it in an other one. If it's in two transactions, then you might take money from one, and try to put it in the other one. But what if there is a rollback in that one? Then you have taken the money from one account an it's just gone.

That's why you need to worry about your own transactions.

By the way, Spring offers transaction support, but it's not its main purpose. That said, it is true that you will find a lot of support choosing spring.

To finally answer your question, I think you should try your solution, but see if it's going to be ACID compliant. If not, you should try to add a dao layer as it is usually not too much of a pain, and add transactions on your service layer.